# Error "Media change: please insert disc labeled..." when installing an application

Tags: software-installation

I've tried several times to install radio tray on my fresh ubuntu 11.10 installation but when I run `~$ sudo apt-get install radiotray`the following dialog pops up at the end of the script:

```
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012)'
in the drive '/cdrom/' and press enter
```

I've performed previous installations of this app on another computer using the same repository and all went smooth. My Ubuntu Oneiric version was installed from a USB flash drive, so don't understand that request from apt-get.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably you still have the following option ticked in your Software Sources:

[image]

If ticked, Ubuntu will install packages from the installation media rather than downloading from the internet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, already unticked. Now cannot run apt-get cause it's still waiting for the CD. Not even allows me to kill the process in system monitor. Would a logout do it?

Comment: give it a try or a reboot.  Check that the untick value in software sources has been retained.

Comment: ... also remember to refresh your software sources via update-manager or `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Tried but didn't work, was wondering if there was other way to stop apt-get from running when this happens without rebooting the system.

Comment: ... I find a quick 30 second reboot resolves these issues...

Comment: thanks again, always appreciate tips from advanced users!

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me on 12.04 (precise).

What got me into this mess in the first place was trying to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 by cdrom.

We must be careful here, whereas it's the "Other software" tab that we enable the cdrom on, it's the "Ubuntu software" tab that we need to disable.

Naturally you can also try this:

1. edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.lst` -> comment out the lines referring to cdrom by removing the `#` in front of it
2. Then execute the command in a terminal `sudo apt-get update`

but know what you're doing!