# Installing npm on Ubuntu 20 requires Ubuntu CD

Tags: nodejs, npm

I have installed node correctly and now trying to install npm

```
sudo apt install npm
```

But I get

```
Media change: please insert the disc labeled  'Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)'
in the drive '/cdrom/' and press [Enter]
```

I don't have a CD I installed Ubuntu using ISO image on a flash disk. How can I solve this?

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver I'm new to Ubuntu and that post helped me https://askubuntu.com/questions/95338/error-media-change-please-insert-disc-labeled-when-installing-an-applicati

Comment: Interesting this doesn't happen to me. Check out the link steeldriver gave you. If that doesn't fix it, what's the output from `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: you can install npm by following the instructions here https://askubuntu.com/a/1200174/890892